# Problem of implementation of Path Payment in a Wallet?

Tags: java-sdk, payments

I made a Java implementation of a Path Payment.

I created 3 accounts. For example:

- the first plays the role of issuer. He issued 2 assets (USD, EUR)
- The second has USD
- The third, EUR.

I created an offer with the EUR account to have the USD.

Finally, I make a Path Payment from the USD account to EUR, but the `response.isSuccess()` method always returns false.

`SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);`

What to do in this case?

```
public void pathPayment(String from, String to, String assetSource, String assetDest, String maxAmount,
                               String amountDest, String memo) {
        System.out.println(" Transfering  from : " + from);
        System.out.println(" Transfering  to : " + to);
        System.out.println(" Transfering amount Source : " + maxAmount);
        System.out.println(" Transfering amountDest : " + amountDest);
        System.out.println(" Transfering  memo : " + memo);
        Network.useTestNetwork();
        Server server = new Server(network);
        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(accountRepository.findByAccountName(from).get(0).getPrivateKey());
        KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId(accountRepository.findByAccountName(to).get(0).getPublicKey());

        // First, check to make sure that the destination account exists.
// You could skip this, but if the account does not exist, you will be charged
// the transaction fee when the transaction fails.
// It will throw HttpResponseException if account does not exist or there was another error.
        AccountResponse destAccount = null;
        try {
            destAccount = server.accounts().account(destination);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        AccountResponse sourceAccount = null;
        try {
            sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Asset sendAsset = getAsset(assetSource, source.getAccountId());
        Asset destAsset = getAsset(assetDest, destination.getAccountId());
        //if(sendAsset==null || destAsset==null) {
        //    return false;
        //}
        // Start building the transaction.
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
                .addOperation(new PathPaymentOperation.Builder(sendAsset, maxAmount, destination, destAsset,
                                amountDest).build())
                .addMemo(Memo.text(memo))
                .setTimeout(TIMEOUT_INFINITE)
                .build();
        // Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
        transaction.sign(source);

        // And finally, send it off to Stellar!
        boolean bool=true;
        try {
            SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
            System.out.print("Was submitTransaction successful : ");
            bool = response.isSuccess();
            System.out.println(bool + " " + response.getResultXdr()+ "  "+response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private Asset getAsset(String assetCode, String accountKey){

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(assetCode) || (!StringUtils.isEmpty(assetCode) && assetCode.equalsIgnoreCase("XLM"))){
            return new AssetTypeNative();
        }

        Network.useTestNetwork();
        Server server = new Server(network);
        AccountResponse account = null;
        KeyPair accountK = KeyPair.fromAccountId(accountKey);
        String issuer="";
        System.out.println("Using network : " + network);
        try {
            account = server.accounts().account(accountK);

            System.out.println("Balances for account " + accountKey);
            for (AccountResponse.Balance balance : account.getBalances()) {
                if(balance.getAssetCode().equalsIgnoreCase(assetCode)){
                    issuer = balance.getAssetIssuer().getAccountId();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Asset asset=null;
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(issuer)){
            asset = Asset.createNonNativeAsset(assetCode, KeyPair.fromAccountId(issuer));
        }
        return asset;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of potential issues.

- First, Path Payment is an operation that requires 2 steps

  1. Finding the Path
  2. Building the path payment operation
- The path found in step 1 is used in building the operations

The horizon server has a paths endpoint that you can use to query available paths; see the docs on [Finding Path Payments](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/path-finding.html) and [Payment Path resource](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/path.html) for more information.

The Java SDK has the [`PathsRequestBuilder`](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/requests/PathsRequestBuilder.html) and the [`setPath()`](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/PathPaymentOperation.Builder.html#setPath-org.stellar.sdk.Asset:A-) method for finding and setting a path on an operation. You should check these out.